# Finite series help with an obvious fact

Tags: real-analysis

Hi everyone I apologize is the following question is too stupid but I cannot figure out how use the principle of induction in this obvious fact:

**Definitions**: (Finite series): Let $m,n$ be integers and $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$ for each $m\le i \le n$. The we define the finite sum by the recursive formula:

$\sum_{i=m}^{n}a_i:=0$ whenever $n<m$, and $\,\,\sum_{i=m}^{n+1}a_i:=\big(\sum_{i=m}^{n}a_i\big)+a_{n+1}$ whenever $n\ge m-1$

**Lemma**: Let $m\le n < p$ be integers and let $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$ for each $m\le i \le p$. Then we have $$\sum_{i=m}^{n}a_i+\sum_{i=n+1}^{p}a_i= \sum_{i=m}^{p}a_i $$

The above definition and the principle of induction is the only tools that I have but I cannot figure out how the induction should be, because the negative integers. So, my first thought was $0\le n-m<p-m$ but again this will prove it in the next lemma. So I'm not sure of how to begin. Could somebody give some hint please?

Sorry if I no put my first attempt, but this is basically an assumption of $m\ge 0$ but the problem with this is again to reach the negative case the lemma that I need, for change the indices, is after this one.

If I understand correctly, first I need to show that whenever we have a sentence $P(n)$ whose domain is the set of the integers: where 1) $P(N_0)$ is true for some $N_0\in \mathbb{Z}$, and 2) $P(n)\implies P(n+1)$ for each $n\ge N_0$. Then $P(n)$ is true for every $n\ge N_0$, using this fact the proof becomes almost trivial.

Proof: Let $Q(k)$  be the predicate "$P(k+N_0)$ is true for $k\ge 0$". Then the base case is when $k=0$, and clearly holds by hypothesis (since $P(N_0)$ is assumed to be true). Now we may assume $Q(k)$ be true for $k\ge 0$. Thus, this means $P(k+N_0)$ is true and since $k+N_0\ge N_0$ we must have $P(k+1+N_0)$ is true, and thus $Q(k+1)$ holds, which close the induction. Then, $Q(k)$ is true for each $k\ge 0$, i.e., $P(k+N_0)$ is true for $k\ge 0$. Setting $n=k+N_0$, this would imply $P(n)$ hold for each $n\ge N_0$.

Now using the above claim let us fix $m,n$ as arbitrary integers such that $m\le n$ and we can use $p=m+1$ as our base case. Thus, $\sum_{i=m}^{n}a_i+\sum_{i=n+1}^{n+1} a_i=\sum_{i=m}^{n}a_i+ a_{n+1}=\sum_{i=m}^{n+1}a_i $, which prove the base case. Suppose the lemma hold for some $p\ge n+1$; we will show that also hold form $p+1$.

Then, $\sum_{i=m}^{n}a_i+\sum_{i=n+1}^{p+1}a_i=\sum_{i=m}^{n}a_i+\sum_{i=n+1}^{p}a_i+a_{p+1}$ and by inductive hypothesis we already know that $\sum_{i=m}^{n}a_i+\sum_{i=n+1}^{p}a_i=\sum_{i=m}^{p}a_i$. Thus, we have $\sum_{i=m}^{p}a_i+a_{p+1}= \sum_{i=m}^{p+1}a_i$. Hence the lemma hold for each $p>n$

What do you think is this last one correct? Thanks to everybody :)

Comment: Since you have $m \leqslant n < p$, you don't need to deal with negative integers. Make an induction on $k = p-(n+1)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Maybe I'm wrong but this not need at the final a change of indices (because if this is the case in  the part b of this lemma is when we'll deal with this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) For $p= n+1$

$$\sum_{i=m}^{n}a_i+\sum_{i=n+1}^{n+1}a_i= \sum_{i=m}^{n}a_i+\sum_{i=n+1}^{n}a_i + a_{n+1}= \sum_{i=m}^{n}a_i+0 + a_{n+1}= \sum_{i=m}^{n}a_i + a_{n+1}= \sum_{i=m}^{n+1}a_i$$ so the inductive hypothesis is true for $p=n+1$.

(2) For $p\gt n+1$ assume the inductive hypothesis is true for $p=k-1$ and then 
$$\sum_{i=m}^{n}a_i+\sum_{i=n+1}^{k}a_i = \sum_{i=m}^{n}a_i+\sum_{i=n+1}^{k-1}a_i +a_k = \sum_{i=m}^{k-1}a_i +a_k= \sum_{i=m}^{k}a_i$$ so the inductive hypothesis is true for $p=k$.

(3) So by induction the hypothesis is true for all $p \gt$ n.

Comment: Only a question about your magnificent explanation: how do we know that $p$ is a non-negative integer (natural number) to apply the induction principle or this doesn't matter? This is basically the principal problem to me. Thanks.

Comment: You know $m\le n < p$ are integers from the question.  It does not matter whether they are positive, negative or zero for the proof.

Comment: Sorry Henry but this is difficult to grasp for me. But what not the principle of induction only works in the case of natural numbers?

Comment: This is the only point that confuse me because if we can prove something using the principle of induction does not necessarily hold for each integer, well this is a point which is treat in the book (Tao's notes). But out of this point your explanation is pretty clear, thanks for take your time.